# Failed to start adb -- APK doesn't start after rebuilding with apktool

Tags: android, apktool

I have APK file, I drop it with mouse to my android emulator, it loads successfully. Then I use following commands to repack APK:

> apktool d -s app-debug.apk
>
> cd app-debug
>
> apktool b

I get this error when I drag and drop new APK file. I need -s key to preserve .dex file (I need to replace DEX, but I have same problem when replace) and avoid decompile/compile step:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me uninstalling previous version of application helped. 
Using **adb** from command line helped to identify error message.